# Unity third person controller and hills

Tags: unity, third-person-view

So I've been building a game and using the out of the box unity third person controller demo stuff.

I found that even the tiniest of slopes seems to stop the "dude" dead in his tracks.

Is there an easy way to adjust the sensitivity on the scripts somewhere?

I tried messing with the sensitivity options in the input options setup thinking that it might help but it didn't and I don't really want to go messing about in the scripts unless I really have to because i end up complicating my life when I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming it uses Unity's Character Controller component - you can adjust the slope limit to work for hills too.

You can read more about it here:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-CharacterController.html

Comment: OMG ... just realised im being a total tit ... i'll shut up now !!